# phpMyAdmin Strange permissions #1142 error after deleting a table record with success

Tags: phpmyadmin

A have a live/production *CentOS 6.8* server with *Nginx*, *PHP* (multiple versions), MySQL 5.7.18 and latest (when writing this question) *phpMyAdmin 4.7.0*.

This server is running for many years and with no problems, but recently I noticed a problem when I tried to delete a record from a table using phpMyAdmin, I got the following error:

> **#1142 - SELECT command denied to user 'test_user'@'localhost' for
>   table 'pma__tracking'**

Strange thing is that it **deletes** the record but it can't refresh the result after the deletion! Also, **all SELECT queries work** and every data browse successfully fetches data on each table!

I have each database to has its' own user with all privileges granted.

I have properly installed `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser']` and `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass']` and all the tables exists inside `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';` database.

My question is, why is this happening and how can I fix it? It's strange for me, because I expect that the user defined inside phpMyAdmin config should access `pmadb` (`'pma'@'localhost'`) and the tables in it and NOT the user that connects to a database!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run into the same problem today. The problem occures every time, you want to modify data in tables with UPDATE / INSERT / DELETE.

They picked the wrong user to perform the (tracking) database query.
I found a patch in the following link.
Because it is not my solution, i just link to the guy who wrote the code.

https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/13214

So, we either can patch it by ourselves or wait for next phpmyadmin release.

Comment: This was really buggning me and I thought it might be a PMA bug. Thank you.